# integral of Beltrami differential times quadratic differential over Riemann surface in terms of contour integrals

Tags: reference-request, differential-forms, riemann-surfaces

In [their review of string perturbation theory](https://inspirehep.net/literature/261475) equation 2.149, D’Hoker and Phong start from a surface integral of a Beltrami differential $\mu$ times a quadratic differential $b$ over a Riemann surface, and they convert that to a contour integral of the quadratic differential $b$ alone.

They do not give enough details for me (new to Beltrami differentials) to figure out how to do this kind of thing in practice, though. I do get the impression they’re rather cavalier about *something*, given that contour integrals of quadratic differentials are not coordinate invariant. I’ve been Googling around, but without much to show for it.

So, can anyone help me find references/reviews either explaining explicitly how to do this (for example, given the Beltrami differential $\mu$ corresponding to the modification of one certain element of the period matrix, how do I compute $\iint b\mu = \oint_? b\ldots$ for an arbitrary holomorfic/meromorfic quadratic differential $b$?), or explaining the concepts they use (quasiconformal vector fields written in terms of functions with unit step)?

Thank you for any help you can give me!